# Delete table if exist

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

How to drop a table in `database.mdf` if it exists? The table exists in the database, but I can't drop it and get an error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ''Talise Company-a''.'

It seems the problem is my string `symbolName` because when I create a "test" table and use "test" instead string it works fine

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c4uMH.jpg)

```
string symbolName = dt.Rows[1][0].ToString();

SqlConnection condb2 = new SqlConnection(strConnection);

condb2.Open();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ['" + symbolName + "']) DROP ['" + symbolName + "']", condb2);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();

condb2.Close();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use DROP TABLE

```
 DROP TABLE  ['" + symbolName + "']"
```

and you could use also

```
DROP TABLE  IF EXISTS
```

avoiding the unuseful select

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/sql/t-sql/statements/drop-table-transact-sql

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ['" + symbolName + 
        "']) DROP TABLE ['" + symbolName + "']", condb2);
```

or  starting from SQL Server 2016 CTP3 you can use this feature

```
 SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(" DROP TABLE ['" + symbolName + "']  IF EXISTS", condb2);
```

Comment: Maybe update my code cause im so newbie on SQL atleast i can understand much better

Comment: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near 'EXISTS'.'

Comment: starting from SQL Server 2016 CTP3 you can use this feature   answer updated ..  if you have previous version  you can use the first  ..

Comment: tnx so much , i owe you a rep

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.all_objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('TABLE_NAME') AND type IN ('U'))
    DROP TABLE TABLE_NAME
```

Comment: Or you could just use the *more focused* `sys.tables` view: `IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE Name = N'TABLE_NAME')...`

Answer (score 1):

You forget to mentioned table word after drop word.

```
 IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM ['" + symbolName + "']) DROP Table ['" + symbolName + "']", condb2
```